# changing javascript variable and function name from java using rhino or closure compiler

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, google-closure-compiler

I want to be able to change the variables and functions name in a javascript file based on certain conditions and then output the modified javascript. This is similar to what a javascript minifier does.
Here is an example:
I have this javascript code

```
var something=5;
something++;
function doSomething(n){
   alert(n);
}
doSomething(something):
```

Now I want to replace the `something` and `doSomething` with `somethingElse` and `doSomethingElse` and return the following javascript code:

```
var somethingElse=5;
somethingElse++;
function doSomethingElse(n){
   alert(n);
}
doSomethingElse(somethingElse):
```

I think this can be done in rhino or google closure compile(which is based on rhino), but don't know how. I'm also open to other suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Is your actual `something` a substring of `somethingElse`?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy no, I just gave a simple example. you can replace `something` with `blablabla` if you want

Comment: Are you actually trying to do minification of some sort? Can you offer a more concrete and specific example to what you are trying to accomplish so that we better understand your intent and goal? Also, can you please state what you actually have attempted so that this conforms to the SO "good question" guidelines?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary yes, I'm trying to do something similar to minification, but I only want to change certain variables(and functions) name depending on what their value is. What I'm trying to do is some sort of javascript code generator where the user sets some input code, and I generate a similar code but with different variable name(based on certain conditions)

Answer (score 5):

Rhino is just a parser, so it wouldn't really help except in the simplest of cases.

Closure-compiler technically can do this, but doesn't officially support directed renaming.

The following technique is used for incremental compilation. Using map files, the compiler tries (but does not guarantee) to honor previous renaming for variables and properties. You *might* make this work using the following steps, but there are no guarantees that it will work in all cases:

### Step 1

Create a variable map file using the following syntax (one entry per line)

```
varname:renamedname
```

### Step 2

Use the variable renaming as part of the compilation command

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js inputfile.js \
  --variable_map_input_file varrenaming.txt
```

Note that all normal renaming rules still apply. If a variable wasn't renamed previously, this won't cause it to be renamed now.